# jQuery sum on change keyup() and output in Text box

Tags: jquery, sum, onkeyup

I have the following jQuery code for finding the sum of all table rows, now it finds the sum on keyup. I want the sum to be already calculated. I wanted to have a hidden field like an input with a value, so the sum is automatically calculated.

Now there is an input, the user writes some number and than he gets the sum, I am trying to get the sum automatically. it's work but **I need the output print in text box**.... for this code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td  colspan ="2" align="right">
            Sum :
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="sum"><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" />
        </td>
        </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    calculateSum();

    $(".txt").live("keydown keyup", function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
        }
        else if (this.value.length != 0){
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **val()** to set the value in the textbox like this:

```
$("#sum input").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

**Html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="40px">1</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="summation">
        <td  colspan ="2" align="right">
            Sum :
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id='sum1' name="input" />
        </td>
        </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    calculateSum();

    $(".txt").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
        }
        else if (this.value.length != 0){
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        }
    });

    $("input#sum1").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

[**Here is working Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/35At5/)

Comment: in your calculateSum function last line replace that line with this one simply

Comment: <input type="text" id='input' name="input" />

i have use this text box for o/p

Comment: then do like this: $("#sum input#input").val(sum.toFixed(2));

Comment: you are welcome and in fiddle you were doing it with pure javascript in your page remember to include latest jquery file to make it work

Comment: i have working on student report cards in which i have getting some other problem in my case i have fill multiple student report cards at a time and  in one Student report cards Calculate work very well but in second student Case it not Work remember i have use same  Fields for second student.....

Comment: If you provide fiddle I can help,  and mark it answer if your issue resolved

Comment: Provide fiddle it will be easy to help in fiddlr

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** here:

```
$("#sum input").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

instead of:

```
$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```